# Turn off imported app's AdminConfig in a Django Project

Tags: django, django-admin, django-apps

I have project, where i am utilizing an imported project, but I do not want the imported project's sections appearing in the automatic admin portal. is there away to override a projects adminConfig via configuration/code?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want `admin.site.unregister(Model)`. Just add that in any admin.py file, import the Models from the project you're using, and then unregister them from the admin interface.

Comment: Great! thanks Jens Astrup! I'll try this out and mark this accepted when I get to test this out!